# fill articlenumber automatically after writing articlename

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a HTML `<form>` and im creating it with [php](/questions/tagged/php). It contains three `<input>` fields. 
The second `<input>` field should be filled automatically, when the first one is filled. A HTTP request is triggered over an API. The request works fine and puts out the article number. I tested it already.

The problem is, that it has to run the request and fill the field, whenever the other field is filled.
I have tried it with jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name*='artNr1']").click(function(){
      .get("artikelnamen_suchen.php", nummeruebergeben($_POST['artName1']));
    });
});
<script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

[Form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Em5U.png)

Comment: Please remember that StackOverflow is an global community. :-) I appreciate your thanks, but want to remind you to use the english language, even for your comments that are clearly directed to users that can understand the language. Other people might find your comment useful as well and you exclude them by using another language than english.

Comment: :D
no, i dont have.
i have a php-function. do i need ajax? 
dont know ajax.

i GET the articlenames and articlenumbers.

Comment: i just need to get the input field (articleName).
with the articleName i can get the articlenumber.
but how do i get the articlename to my php-function?

Comment: Posted an answer. Please remove your comments, since they are no longer of need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to insert the `$` (dollar sign) before `.get()`

Your code should be like this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name*='artNr1']").click(function(){
      $.get("artikelnamen_suchen.php", nummeruebergeben($_POST['artName1']));
    });
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) provides the [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) method to listen to change events, e.g. on `<input>` fields. You can replace the `click()` handler with it.

```
$("input[name*='artNr1']").change(function(){
  $.get("artikelnamen_suchen.php", nummeruebergeben($_POST['artName1']));
});
```

The problem with your code is, that you call [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)`.get()` with the PHP variable `$_POST['artName1']`. This shows two flaws:

1. If the replacement with that PHP value works, it is evaluated on server side and therefore never replaced with the current value from the `<input>`, that is present on client side
2. You seem to expect the value to be transferred via POST, but you use [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)`.get()` to transfer it via GET.

To address the first flaw, you need to use the value from the first `<input>` instead of the value that was evaluated from PHP.

```
$("input[name*='artNr1']").change(function(){
    var articleNumber = $(this).val();
    //TODO: $.get("artikelnamen_suchen.php", nummeruebergeben($_POST['artName1']));
});
```

Because you are currently in the `onChange` handler of the first `<input>` field, it is available as the `this` context in that function. With [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)`.val()` you can access its current value.

To address the second flaw, you can use two different ways. Either use the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)`.post()`mehtod to send your data as POST to PHP:

```
$("input[name*='artNr1']").change(function(){
    var articleNumber = $(this).val();
    $.post("artikelnamen_suchen.php", {
        'artName1': articleNumber
    }).success(function(result){
        //Work with the result here
    });
});
```

Or provide the information as GET and access it in PHP as a `$_GET` field instead of `$_POST`:

In [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```
$("input[name*='artNr1']").change(function(){
    var articleNumber = $(this).val();
    $.get("artikelnamen_suchen.php?artName1=" + articleNumber)
        .success(function(result){
            //Work with the result here
        });
});
```

---

In [php](/questions/tagged/php)

---

```
$articleNumber = $_GET['artName1'];
... //Use $articleName instead of $_POST['artName1'] in your PHP code.
```

After that you can work with `result` to replace the value in your second input. But thats another question... :-D